# Windows OS option now showing up on Google Compute Engine VM

Tags: windows, google-compute-engine

I am new to Google Compute and want to create a VM instance having Windows Server 2012. But Windows OS option is not available for any location or machine type options.

Does Google Compute not provide Window based VMs?

Regards,
Suraj

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Google Compute Engine provides  Windows Server 2008 R2 Datacenter Edition images for your instances. However, they are in Limited Preview and you need to fill out [the sign up form](https://docs.google.com/a/google.com/forms/d/1_U28LyQztpjlAwR43zNxX2V2bOzAfA3fGEeQ97KrXYM/viewform) as per [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/operating-systems#windows_server_images).

Once you receive by email that your request has been approved, you'll be able to create Windows instances through the Developers Console and the command line as well.